# I would like to reload database results in Node.JS mysql

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use Node.js as my server backend implementing MySQL, event and MQTT module.

This first connects to DB and query results are saved in array.
Rows with status column = 1 must be loaded all the time, but this column is changed by the user from web. So I thought results must be refreshed every few seconds(minutes are fine).

I will post only part of the code where I guess it's important.

```
con.query("select * from recipe WHERE status=1", function(err, rows,fields){
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        setValue(rows);
    }
});

function setValue(value) {
    someVar = value;

    for (var i in value) {

        switch(value[i].condition1) {
            case "temp":
            eventEmitter.emit("event1");
            break;
            case "time":
            eventEmitter.emit("event2");
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to execute the query every `x` seconds?

Comment: Slawomir Wozniak // Yes!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `setTimeout()` function.

Let's wrap the query into a function, for convenience.

```
function reload(){
  con.query("select * from recipe WHERE status=1", function(err, rows,fields){
    if(err) {
     throw err;
    } else {
     setValue(rows);
    }
  });
}
```

Then, just put it into `setTimeout()` function.

```
setTimeout(reload, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. However there seems to be a problem. Instead of refreshing, I guess tasks are just added. So the code that executes when condition is met runs multiple times. (eg. refreshed every 10 sec. waited for 40 sec. so the code ran 4 times)